# Connecting an iPhone to VMware freezes macOS and crashes the iPhone?

Tags: vmware

I've been using macOS as a guest running on VMware 12.5 for a while for iOS development successfully. My iPhone was recognized by the guest os and usable with xcode to test the Apps.

But since a few updates (I can't tell if it is VMware update - vmplayer / vmware worstation 12.5.6 build-5528349 or linux 4.11.3) when I connect my iPhone, the guest os freezes.

If I wait for a few minutes, then the iPhone gets disconnected (no error message is shown) and the guest OS works again, however in any case when I physically disconnect my iPhone from cable, it crashes and reboots automatically.
I've tried with two different iPhones, same result.

My iPhone is already registered for development and my VM USB is set to USB 2.0.
Anyone else is having the same issue?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. My host is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I'm having the same problem using Ubuntu 17.10 and kernel 4.13.0-46-generic

Comment: I don’t have enough reputation to answer, but using USB 1.1 fixes the crashing as per VMWares docs on this issue. If 12MB/s USB speed is ok for you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with iOS 10.3.2

Connecting device with iOS 10.2 works fine

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here using MacOS Sierra (also El Captain) on VMWare 12/iPhone 5s/Arch Linux host.

#### Problem fixed after these steps

- Before starts VMWare mount your device on the host. The iphone will ask to set this computer as "trust"
- Open VMWare (using USB 3.0)
- Mount the USB device in the guest OS, the phone will ask AGAIN to authorize this second hardware.

I can confirm that works both on Sierra and El Captain. You may need to try different sequences after that. For example keeping the plug connected and the device mounted before start your virtual machine seems to works better than in the first mount.

Comment: I've tried your solution but still no luck... I'm on Arch too with latest kernel and running vmware 12.5.6. What's you configuration?

Comment: Vmware or hardware configuration?

Comment: Look, i just could be able to connect the device without freezing. After that it does not work stable as i would like. I am still testing other cables (every cable i use i got a different situation), but the procedure mentioned above was enough to fix it (to me). Also i am testing some USB over Network based on client/server service that works very well using any USB device, except the apple devices (iPhone 5). Good luck my friend. Having news will let you know